# What should be return if any Exception Occures in the DateTime type function?

Tags: c#, .net

Here is the code for tha same. I am getting error in the catch block because I want know what can be return there

```
public static DateTime ToDate(this object val)
{
    try
    {
       return Convert.ToDateTime(val);
    }
    catch 
    {
        return ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not throw the exception? If something is wrong, fix it.

Comment: You don't want to handle the exception?

Comment: Don't use try-catch but `DateTime.TryParse` and return `DateTime?` if the conversion failed.

Comment: This is entirely context-specific. Sometimes you really want to ignore bad data - other times you should stop immediately. We can't tell.

Comment: Here's the thing: We certainly don't have the context to decide what should be returned here. I'm thinking you probably don't either, at this point in the code. Therefore the correct answer is: Throw the exception and let code at a higher level that *does* know the context decide.

Comment: Make return type as NULLABLE  `DateTime?` and return `NULL` from Catch Block

Comment: Also, aren't you effectively just re-implementing `Convert.ToDateTime`? Why write this method at all?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: he _is using_ `Convert.ToDateTime`. But since there's no `Convert.TryToDateTime` it seems he tries to support the `TryParse` pattern on `Object` with exception handling.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - all the OP seems to be adding at this point is a `try`/`catch` around it, and they *don't know what to do when they catch*.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: he expects an exception so invalid dates which `Convert.ToDateTime` does not handle. So imo the reason for this method is pretty clear. He just don't know what to return when the conversion failed. One way would be `bool` and `DateTime` as `out`-parameter. Same as `DateTime.TryParse`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use exception handling to try-cast to `DateTime`. Use `DateTime.TryParse` and return `Nullable<DateTime>` if the conversions fails.

For example:

```
public static DateTime? ToDate(this object val, IFormatProvider formatProvider = null)
{
    if(val ==  null) return null;
    if(val is DateTime) return (DateTime) val;
    if(val is DateTime?) return (DateTime?) val;
    if(formatProvider == null) formatProvider = System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo;

    string dateStr = val.ToString();
    DateTime dt;
    if(DateTime.TryParse(dateStr, formatProvider, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
        return dt;
    return null;
}
```

Now you can differentiate between a valid `DateTime` and one that couldn't be parsed:

```
object dtObj = "2016-02-11";
DateTime? dtorNot = dtObj.ToDate(); // valid,  dtorNot.Value contains the DateTime
dtObj = "foo";
dtorNot = dtObj.ToDate();          // invalid, dtorNot.HasValue == false
```

Answer (score 1):

You could either use a [sentinel value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value) like DateTime.MaxValue (or MinValue), or you could return null (as long as you change the signature to **DateTime?** (nullable DateTime)

Answer (score 0):

It should be the blatantly obvious value to return in this case.

If there isn't a blatantly obvious value then you're doing your exception handling in the wrong place. Or else perhaps you should be catching that exception and throwing a different type.